# MouseListener doesn't call mouseClicked method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, mouselistener

I thought I implemented `MouseListener` correctly, but when I click on the canvas it doesn't reach the line `System.out.println("Click registered");`

All the tutorials I've looked at implement a mouse listener the way I did.

The program compiles and everything works except for the mouse listener.

```
package ttt;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    public static Field field = new Field();
    public static Game game = new Game();
    public static TTTCanvas tttcanvas = new TTTCanvas();
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 700;
    
    public Frame() 
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(400, 400, width, height);
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        add(tttcanvas);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {  
        System.out.println("Click registered");
        int x = field.getFieldfromPixel(e.getX());
        int y = field.getFieldfromPixel(e.getY());
        game.updateField(x, y);
    }
    
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: You should NOT be using static variables. This indicates incorrect design.

Comment: @camickr the way i understood static variables is there can only be one instance of them and for example i use field in 3 classes i think but i want to use the same field in all 3 classes so i used static any tips on how to do it better?

Comment: Program design it too complex of a discussion. I can't suggest how you should fix the design. In general if one class needs access to another class that it doesn't create, then you need to pass it as a parameter to that class. As ControlAltDelete mentioned in a comment below you may want to read up on MVC design.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me when I remove:

```
//add(tttcanvas);
```

A MouseEvent is only dispatched to a single component.

Your TTTCanvas class must also have a MouseListner, so it is receiving the event.

Not sure what your exact requirement is so I would guess you could either:

1. add a second MouseListener to the TTTCanvas class or combine the logic of both listeners into one listener, or
2. remove the listener from the TTTCanvas class

Some code to demonstrate my answer:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
//    public static Field field = new Field();
//    public static Game game = new Game();
//    public static TTTCanvas tttcanvas = new TTTCanvas();
//    static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 700;

    public Frame()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(400, 400, width, height);
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        //add(tttcanvas);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(700, 400) );
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("panel listener");
            }
        });

        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("frame listener");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> new Frame() );
    }
}
```

1. if you click on the red panel you see "panel listener" because the panel receives the event not the frame.
2. if you click on the grey you see "frame listener" because no other component has been added to the CENTER of the frames BorderLayout, so the frame receives the MouseEvent.

Comment: now its only in the ttt canvas class works also thank you. i thought it would make more sense in the frame class

Answer (score 1):

Add the mouselistener to your ttt canvas

```
package ttt;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    public static Field field = new Field();
    public static Game game = new Game();
    public static TTTCanvas tttcanvas = new TTTCanvas();
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 700;
    
    public Frame() 
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        setBounds(400, 400, width, height);
        setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        add(tttcanvas);
        tttcanvas.addMouseListener(this); //changed here
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {  
        System.out.println("Click registered");
        int x = field.getFieldfromPixel(e.getX());
        int y = field.getFieldfromPixel(e.getY());
        game.updateField(x, y);
    }
    
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}  
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Comment: @camickr I know you are the source for all things Swing, but I don't think the advice you gave here is very good. The MouseListener should be in the `Controller` class (MVC pattern). That's probably the TTTCanvas class, but without more information we just don't know... Plus, introducing MVC if OP is unaware is (IMO) more useful advice

Comment: @ControlAltDel   The reason the original code doesn't work is because a MouseListener is already added to the TTTCanvas class as I explained in my answer.  The main point I was trying to make is that it doesn't make sense (to me) to add a MouseListener to the TTTCanvas class in two places. I would find it confusing to have two listeners each added from a different class. I was not trying to introduce MVC design, since I don't really understand it.

Comment: @camickr mouselistener was only in the frame class not in the tttcanvas class

Comment: @warriorloewe The posted code is not complete. This is why you should always add an [mre] so we don't need to guess. Adding the listener to the frame will work. However, since it didn't, then that tells me that a listener was also added to the TTTCanvas class somewhere else., which prevents the frame from receiving the event. I added a quick demo to my answer to demonstrate this concept. Depending on where you click you get a different message.